# how to bind two or more datatable and display in one gridview as one result table

Tags: datatable

I have one table `onetime.its` columns are:
`columns(masterno,requisitionno,dept,userid,mat_code,material_long_text,prq_no,step1_userid,step1_approvaldate,step2_userid,step2_approvaldate,step3_userid,step3_approvaldate)`

But I have two conditions. My queries are as follows:

Query1:

Dim dt1 As New DataTable()

```
Dim dataadapater1 As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from copyonetime where step2_userid is null and userid is not null ", New SqlConnection(connectionString))
dataadapater1.Fill(dt1)
GridView1.DataSource = dt1
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Query2:

Dim dt As New DataTable()

```
Dim dataadapater As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from copyonetime where step3_userid is null and step2_userid is not null ", New SqlConnection(connectionString))
dataadapater.Fill(dt)
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

How to bind these both tables and display both the datatable in one gridview as one result table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new datatable-DT3 and Copy data from first datatable-DT1 and Merge with second datatable-DT2 then bind datatable-DT3 to gridview.

```
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable

        dt1.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
        dt1.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
        dt1.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

        dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Kevin", "Rodger")
        dt1.Rows.Add(3, "Donald", "Kapp")
        dt1.Rows.Add(4, "Betty", "Hanna")

        Dim dt2 As New DataTable

        dt2.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
        dt2.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
        dt2.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

        dt2.Rows.Add(5, "Mike", "McAlister")
        dt2.Rows.Add(6, "Jason", "Peixito")
        dt2.Rows.Add(7, "Michael", "Jhonson")
        dt2.Rows.Add(8, "Josef", "Horn")

        Dim dt3 As New DataTable
        dt3.Columns.Add("Id", GetType(Integer))
        dt3.Columns.Add("FirstName", GetType(String))
        dt3.Columns.Add("LastName", GetType(String))

        dt3 = dt1.Copy()
        dt3.Merge(dt2)

        GridView1.DataSource = dt3
        GridView1.DataBind()
```